# GetVolumePathName() failed with ERROR 158: ERROR_NOT_LOCKED

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

GetVolumePathName() API failed and GetLastError() returned ERROR 158: ERROR_NOT_LOCKED.

What is the reason for this error and how to overcome it?

Comment: Would you mind showing some code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some example code how you call that method? Your call should look like following:

```
_TCHAR Buffer[MAX_PATH + 1] = {0};
if (GetVolumePathName(TEXT("C:\\Windows"), Buffer, MAX_PATH)) {
    // Buffer should return C:\
    // GetLastError() is undefined here
} else {
    // returns GetLatError();
}
```

However you should keep in mind, that GetLastError() is undefined if GetVolumePathName() call was successful. May be this coould have caused that error code?